# iterating over connected components

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, connected-components

I want to iterate over each connected component of an undirected graph containing ~10<sup>7</sup> vertices. i.e. I want to call some function f(V<sub>i</sub>) on each vector V<sub>1</sub>...V<sub>k</sub> where V<sub>i</sub> is a vector containing the data attached to each node in the ith connected component of the graph.

What are the fastest algorithms for doing this?

My first thoughts were:

1. Store all unvisited vertices in a heap, then repeatedly take a vertex from the heap, use DFS to find its connected component V<sub>i</sub>, call f(V<sub>i</sub>) and delete all vertices in the component from the heap.
2. Find a variant of union-find disjoint sets which not only supports efficient set union but also makes it efficient to iterate over the sets and to find their members. (Is this possible?)

Comment: Certainly DFS is a way to do this, however it may depend on if you're trying to optimize this for a one-off computation, or for a computation that will happen often. With some more bookeeping, you wouldn't need to rediscover connected components each time.

Comment: Why do you need a heap for this? Use a simple hashset, DFS/BFS both work and are the most optimal you can do.

Comment: Can we assume that you store the graph as adjacency lists? Can we assume that vertices are numbered from 0 to N-1, where N is the total number of vertices?

Comment: @pkacprzak Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run the classic [connected components algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling). Typically, this manipulates a [disjoint-sets data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).
2. Create a hash table mapping nodes to linked lists of nodes.
3. Iterate over each node

   a. Find the representative node in the disjoint-sets data structure

   b. Create a linked list for the representative node in the hash table, if necessary

   c. Add the node to the linked list associated with the representative node

This takes effectively linear time (i.e., *Θ(|E| + |V|)*, expected (under the widely accepted understanding that disjoint sets is effectively linear time).

You now have a hash table whose number of entries is the number of connected components. Each value is a linked list of all the nodes in the connected component. You can now iterate linearly over anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes DFS is a good option for this. But keep in mind that with the given range 10^7 nodes if you run a recursive DFS you might face troubles with memory. Because in worts case all nodes will make a chain and you will need huge size in stack, causing STACKOVERFLOW( :D )

Try doing:

1. DFS using stack(non recursive DFS) with order O(V+E)   or,
2. Use simply BFS (best choice considering simplicity and number of nodes here) order(V+E)

BFS is usually used for shortest path problems but it can be used in many other applications such as this one. This will take space from heap for the queue data structure, where the usual recursive DFS takes space from stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the graph as adjacency list and vertices are denoted by integers from `1` to `n-1`, then there is no need for union-find or hash tables.

Let's assume that `g[v]` is the list (vector) of vertices adjacent to `v`. Moreover, let `cc` be the list of lists (vector of vectors), where `cc[i]` denotes vertices in the `i-th` connected component. For implementation purposes, let `visited[v] = true` if and only if we examined `v` in `DFS` routine we are going to use. Then pseudocode looks like that:

```
dfs(v, current_cc):
   visited[v] = true
   current_cc.append(v)
   for u in g[v]:
      if not visited[u]:
         dfs(u, current_cc)

for v = 0 to n-1:
   visited[i] = false

for v = 0 to n-1:
   if not visited[v]:
      current_cc = []
      dfs(v, current_cc)
      cc.append(current_cc)

//From now, cc[i] is a list of vertices in the i-th connected component, 
//so we can easily iterate and call whatever we want on them.
```